# how to use SAS for counts with repeated measures

Tags: count, sas, frequency, descriptor, repeat

I am using a SAS dataset with repeated measures. Each record is an encounter. I have 10000 encounters for 63 subjects (ID numbers repeat for the encounters). Each encounter is associated with a case number (another repeating variable that can occur in multiple records) and a role (ordinal variable). I want to create a profile for each of the 63 subjects showing the number of distinct cases they encountered and a count of the various roles for each encounter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with proc sql:

```
proc sql;
    create table new as
    select id, count(distinct casenum) as ct_casenum, 
        count(distinct role) as ct_role
    from have
    group by id;
quit;
```

`count(distinct casenum)` counts the distinct values of casenum in the group, which in this case is defined by the value of id.